# Remove words in a column .CSV with Batch File

Tags: csv, batch-file, gps, keyword

I have a batch file in the same folder as the a .CSV incoming folder.

The incoming .CSV file has one Column `| GPSPosition |`

The output data looks like `| 21 deg 14' 4.621" S, 159 deg 46' 45.358" W |` and yes it is one big phrase in a column.

I am having trouble determining how to approach the issue, I want to write a .bat file to remove the words "deg" from the values in each row of the column in the .csv file.

Current Result

```
| GPSPosition |
| 21 deg 14' 4.621" S, 159 deg 46' 45.358" W |
| 21 deg 14' 4.621" S, 159 deg 47' 45.358" W |
| 21 deg 14' 4.621" S, 159 deg 48' 45.358" W |
```

Expected Result

```
| GPSPosition |
| 21  14' 4.621" S, 159  46' 45.358" W |
| 21  14' 4.621" S, 159  47' 45.358" W |
| 21  14' 4.621" S, 159  48' 45.358" W |
```

Comment: Stackoverflow.com <https://stackoverflow.com/> is not a
free script/code writing service. Edit *relevant section(s)* of 
what you have tried into your question along with appropriate representative data (use cut/paste) & say what your actual and expected results are. We can try to help with specific problems.
You should also read How do I ask a good question?
<https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask>. Requests for code to be written are off-topic & are likely to be closed. So - are the pipe delimiters within your data? Do you want them retained? "Split @ comma" - so you have 2 columns?

Comment: Excellent, I'm not asking for code to be written; I'm asking for an idea as to where I can start so I can help others with the same problem. I'll remove the last little bit of the question you got hung up on so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65987390.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "indelims=|,"
SET "outdelim=^|"

(
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1,2delims=%indelims%" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "col1=%%b"
 SET "col2=%%c"
 IF DEFINED col2 (
  SET "col1=!col1:deg =!"
  SET "col2=!col2:deg =!"
  ECHO %outdelim%!col1:~1!%outdelim%!col2:~1,-1!%outdelim%
 ) ELSE (
 rem - no col2, so header
  ECHO %outdelim%!col1:~1,-1!%outdelim%Column2header string%outdelim%
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

See `set /?` from the prompt to decipher the `:m,n` syntax. Note that the pipe needs to be escaped (with caret) on output, otherwise `cmd` sees it as a redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple: take each line, replace `deg`  with "nothing"  and output the resulting string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("input.csv") do (
  set "line=%%a"
  set "line=!line:deg =!"
  REM set "line=!line:,=|!"
  echo !line!
))>output.csv
```

Using quotes with the `set` command avoids errors with the pipe symbol, delayed expansion takes care of the pipe with the `echo` command.

(When needed, replace the comma with a pipe symbol too. According to your example output that isn't wanted. But I inserted to code for that; remove the `REM` if you want to use it)